# Did Perl 5.10 mess something up with prototypes?

Tags: perl, prototype, perl5.10

I *know* this type of thing I want to do used to work in 5.8. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to get back there in Perl 5.10?

Here's the module:

```
package TableMod;
use base qw<Exporter>;
our @EXPORT_OK = qw<mod_table>;

use Data::Dumper;
sub mod_table (\%@) { print Dumper( @_ ); }

1;
```

And here is the script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Test::More tests => 4;

sub mod_table_here (\%@) { 
    print Dumper( @_ );
}

use_ok( 'TableMod', 'mod_table' );
can_ok( __PACKAGE__, 'mod_table' );
is( prototype( \&mod_table_here ), '\\%@'
  , q/prototype( \&mod_table_here ) = '\%@'/ 
  );
is( prototype( \&mod_table ), prototype( \&mod_table_here )
   , 'prototypes ARE the SAME!' 
   );
my %table = qw<One 1>;
mod_table_here %table => ( 1, 2, 3, 4 );
#mod_table %table => ( 1, 2, 3, 4 );
mod_table( %table, 1, 2, 3, 4 );
```

All I have to do is uncomment the next to last line and I get:

```
Useless use of modulus (%) in void context at - line 17.
Useless use of a constant in void context at - line 17.
Useless use of a constant in void context at - line 17.
Useless use of a constant in void context at - line 17.
Bareword "mod_table" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at - line 17.
```

It doesn't complain about the local sub, but it loses its mind over the imported one. On top of that despite the tests telling me that I've imported 'mod_table', strict is now confused that it is a bareword!

Not only that but despite the tests telling me that the prototypes are the same, I *can't* pass `%table` as a hashref to the imported sub. Not even if I use the conventional syntax, shown in the last line.

What I get is:

```
1..4
ok 1 - use TableMod;
ok 2 - main->can('mod_table')
ok 3 - prototype( \&mod_table_here ) = '\%@'
ok 4 - prototypes ARE the SAME!
$VAR1 = {
          'One' => '1'
        };
$VAR2 = 1;
$VAR3 = 2;
$VAR4 = 3;
$VAR5 = 4;
$VAR1 = 'One';
$VAR2 = '1';
$VAR3 = 1;
$VAR4 = 2;
$VAR5 = 3;
$VAR6 = 4;
```

Comment: There was the addition of `(_)` prototype, but I don't think it is related.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its because `use_ok` is being called at run-time.  If you add the following then it all works fine:

```
 use TableMod 'mod_table';
```

I normally only keep a single test file with `use_ok` in (normally *00-load.t* or *00-use.t*).  I think Ovid may have written a blog post about this being a good practice?

**Update**:  Found [Ovid's blog post](http://use.perl.org/~Ovid/journal/39074) I was referring to.

/I3az/

Comment: It's not the use_ok() that comes with 5.10.*, it's a problem with use_ok() in all versions. If you don't load the module before Perl has to parse the rest of the source, you don't get the benefit of prototypes or imports.

Comment: @brian - Absolutely correct. When I did a quick test with 5.8.8 the OP code did work, but I can't repeat that now so clearly I'd mucked something up while doing it ;-(    I've amended answer accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

This is the expected result.  The use_ok call is at run-time, so the mod_table sub is only compiled and imported *after* the "call" to it is encountered during compilation, so the "call" to mod_table is interpreted as an illegal bareword.

This code produces the same warnings/error, both on 5.8 and 5.10.

```
perl -e'use strict; use warnings; my %table; mod_table %table => (1,2,3,4)'
```

Because the lack of compile-time import can affect the compiled test code in ways
like this, it's a good idea to use `use` instead of use_ok in all tests except a
test dedicated to just doing the use_ok (potentially with a [BAIL_OUT](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Test::More#BAIL_OUT)).
(Putting the use_ok in a BEGIN block alleviates these kind of problems but can cause
other problems, so isn't a good idea.)